# Iterating a multi dimensional array object using jsrender

Tags: javascript, spring, web, freemarker, jsrender

I am new to jsrender and its templates.I am using a multidimensional array say `myVariable[5][8]` where 5 is row count and 8 is column count and have to create tr tag for each row and td tag for each column.I have no idea how to iterate it.This is how i tried and couldnt proceed.

### My template file

```
{{for myVariable}}

  //It would iterate the myvariable row count
   <tr>
     //And how to iterate the column count in this region
   </tr>
{{/for}}
```

for example i have a variable `myVariable[0][3]={"var":"someVar","id":"someId"}`.How to print the value var from each myvariable object into the td tag inside the tr tag mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

For the inner iteration you need to iterate over the current data item (the inner array):

```
{{for #data}}
```

Actually you can just write:

```
{{for}}
```

since this defaults to the current data item.

There is a full sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/BorisMoore/cGZZP/ which includes data-linking (live data-binding with JsViews). So it uses `{^{for...` (data-linked tag) instead of `{{for...`

With just JsRender that would be:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    {{for myVariable}}
    <tr>
      {{for}}
      <td>
        {{:var}}
      </td>
      {{/for}}
    </tr>
    {{/for}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```